# Конкатенация в Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

День добрый. Нужно объединить в смарти переменные, по аналогу с php

```
$somevar['also'.$another]
```

в смарти это могло бы выглядеть вот так

```
{$row.title_{$l.symb}}
```

есть ли способ?

Comment: $somevar['also'.$another]

Так разве можно?

Comment: да можно и не только так )

Comment: Да

>$array = array('key1'=>'key1','key2'=>'key2','key3'=>'key3',);
>for($i = 1;$i <=3; $i++) {
>    echo $array['key'.$i] . PHP_EOL;
>}

>key1
>key2
>key3

Comment: @Nord001 речь была о смарти..

Comment: Да, я знаю, я отвечал @exec

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{assign var=v value='also'|cat:$another}
{$somevar.$v}
или 
{assign var=v value='title_'|cat:$l.symb}
{$row.$v}
```

думаю смысл понятен.

Comment: А вы проверяли на реальном Smarty, или это чисто теоретически?
Если это реально так, то здорово!

Comment: да проверил

Comment: Здорово, не знал

Comment: О! скоро проверю - отпишу!

Comment: @FLK - оно! преогромнейшее мерси!